# Girls dead monster songs?

Tags: angel-beats

I can't find any girlsdemo songs with English sub they are the band from angel beats. Does anyone know a place I can find videos of all the girls dead monster songs with English subtitles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.animelyrics.com/anime/angelbeats) site is a great for anime lyrics from pretty much any show you can think of.
Youtube is also a great source. I got a ton of results just by searching "girls dead monster english sub"
I'm not sure that you'll be able to find **all** of them, but stuff like [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qi7qYAmPF3E) is all over youtube.